# Cannot upgrade programs

Tags: upgrade, 21.10

I can see there are 64 package upgrades available but I cannot install them for some reason. I'm new to using linux. What should I do?

```
xxxxxx@xxxxxx:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease           
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                    
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease            
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease          
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                        
Hit:8 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease   
Hit:10 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Hit:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
64 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.


xxxxxx@xxxxxx:~$ sudo apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
evolution-data-server/impish 3.40.4-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.40.0-1ubuntu1.1]
ffmpeg/impish 7:4.4-6ubuntu5 amd64 [upgradable from: 7:4.3.2-0+deb11u1ubuntu1]
ghc-prof/impish 8.8.4-2build2 amd64 [upgradable from: 8.8.4-2]
ghc/impish 8.8.4-2build2 amd64 [upgradable from: 8.8.4-2]
gir1.2-gweather-3.0/impish 40.0-3 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.36.1-2]
gjs/impish 1.68.4-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.67.2-2ubuntu1]
gnome-calendar/impish 41.0-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.38.2-1build1]
gnome-settings-daemon-common/impish,impish 40.0.1-1ubuntu3 all [upgradable from: 3.38.1-3ubuntu3.1]
gnome-settings-daemon/impish 40.0.1-1ubuntu3 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.38.1-3ubuntu3.1]
gnome-shell-common/impish,impish 40.5-1ubuntu2 all [upgradable from: 3.38.4-1ubuntu3~21.04.1]
gnome-shell-extension-prefs/impish 40.5-1ubuntu2 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.38.4-1ubuntu3~21.04.1]
gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/impish,impish 70~ubuntu3 all [upgradable from: 69ubuntu1]
gnome-shell-extensions/impish,impish 40.4-2 all [upgradable from: 3.38.2-1]
gnome-shell/impish 40.5-1ubuntu2 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.38.4-1ubuntu3~21.04.1]
guile-2.2-libs/impish 2.2.7+1-6build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.2.7+1-5.4]
libavcodec58/impish 7:4.4-6ubuntu5 amd64 [upgradable from: 7:4.3.2-0+deb11u1ubuntu1]
libavdevice58/impish 7:4.4-6ubuntu5 amd64 [upgradable from: 7:4.3.2-0+deb11u1ubuntu1]
libavfilter7/impish 7:4.4-6ubuntu5 amd64 [upgradable from: 7:4.3.2-0+deb11u1ubuntu1]
libavformat58/impish 7:4.4-6ubuntu5 amd64 [upgradable from: 7:4.3.2-0+deb11u1ubuntu1]
libavutil56/impish 7:4.4-6ubuntu5 amd64 [upgradable from: 7:4.3.2-0+deb11u1ubuntu1]
libcamel-1.2-62/impish 3.40.4-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.40.0-1ubuntu1.1]
libebackend-1.2-10/impish 3.40.4-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.40.0-1ubuntu1.1]
libebook-1.2-20/impish 3.40.4-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.40.0-1ubuntu1.1]
libebook-contacts-1.2-3/impish 3.40.4-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.40.0-1ubuntu1.1]
libecal-2.0-1/impish 3.40.4-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.40.0-1ubuntu1.1]
libedata-book-1.2-26/impish 3.40.4-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.40.0-1ubuntu1.1]
libedata-cal-2.0-1/impish 3.40.4-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.40.0-1ubuntu1.1]
libedataserver-1.2-26/impish 3.40.4-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.40.0-1ubuntu1.1]
libedataserverui-1.2-3/impish 3.40.4-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.40.0-1ubuntu1.1]
libffi-dev/impish 3.4.2-1ubuntu5 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.4~20200819gead65ca871-0ubuntu5]
libgirepository-1.0-1/impish 1.68.0-1build2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.66.1-1build1]
libgjs0g/impish 1.68.4-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.67.2-2ubuntu1]
libglib-object-introspection-perl/impish 0.049-1build1.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.049-1build1]
libglib2.0-0/impish 2.68.4-1ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.68.1-1~ubuntu21.04.1]
libglib2.0-bin/impish 2.68.4-1ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.68.1-1~ubuntu21.04.1]
libglib2.0-dev-bin/impish 2.68.4-1ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.68.1-1~ubuntu21.04.1]
libglib2.0-dev/impish 2.68.4-1ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.68.1-1~ubuntu21.04.1]
libgweather-3-16/impish 40.0-3 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.36.1-2]
libllvm12/impish 1:12.0.1-8build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:12.0.0-3ubuntu1~21.04.2]
libp11-kit0/impish 0.23.22-1build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.23.22-1]
libpostproc55/impish 7:4.4-6ubuntu5 amd64 [upgradable from: 7:4.3.2-0+deb11u1ubuntu1]
libpython2.7-minimal/impish 2.7.18-8build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.18-6]
libpython2.7-stdlib/impish 2.7.18-8build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.18-6]
libpython3.9-minimal/impish 3.9.7-2build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.9.5-3ubuntu0~21.04.1]
libpython3.9-stdlib/impish 3.9.7-2build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.9.5-3ubuntu0~21.04.1]
libpython3.9/impish 3.9.7-2build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.9.5-3ubuntu0~21.04.1]
libqt5webengine-data/impish,impish 5.15.6+dfsg-1 all [upgradable from: 5.15.3+dfsg-5ubuntu1]
libqt5webengine5/impish 5.15.6+dfsg-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.15.3+dfsg-5ubuntu1]
libqt5webenginecore5/impish 5.15.6+dfsg-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.15.3+dfsg-5ubuntu1]
libswresample3/impish 7:4.4-6ubuntu5 amd64 [upgradable from: 7:4.3.2-0+deb11u1ubuntu1]
libswscale5/impish 7:4.4-6ubuntu5 amd64 [upgradable from: 7:4.3.2-0+deb11u1ubuntu1]
libwayland-client0/impish 1.19.0-2build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.18.0-2~exp1.1]
libwayland-server0/impish 1.19.0-2build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.18.0-2~exp1.1]
p11-kit-modules/impish 0.23.22-1build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.23.22-1]
p11-kit/impish 0.23.22-1build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.23.22-1]
python2.7-minimal/impish 2.7.18-8build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.18-6]
python2.7/impish 2.7.18-8build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.18-6]
python3-cffi-backend/impish 1.14.6-1build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.14.5-1]
python3-gi-cairo/impish 3.40.1-1build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.38.0-4]
python3-gi/impish 3.40.1-1build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.38.0-4]
python3.9-minimal/impish 3.9.7-2build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.9.5-3ubuntu0~21.04.1]
python3.9/impish 3.9.7-2build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.9.5-3ubuntu0~21.04.1]
qml-module-qtwebengine/impish 5.15.6+dfsg-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.15.3+dfsg-5ubuntu1]
yaru-theme-gnome-shell/impish,impish 21.10.2 all [upgradable from: 21.04.1]

xxxxxx@xxxxxx:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  evolution-data-server ffmpeg ghc ghc-prof gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gjs
  gnome-calendar gnome-settings-daemon gnome-settings-daemon-common
  gnome-shell gnome-shell-common gnome-shell-extension-prefs
  gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock gnome-shell-extensions guile-2.2-libs
  libavcodec58 libavdevice58 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavutil56
  libcamel-1.2-62 libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-20 libebook-contacts-1.2-3
  libecal-2.0-1 libedata-book-1.2-26 libedata-cal-2.0-1 libedataserver-1.2-26
  libedataserverui-1.2-3 libffi-dev libgirepository-1.0-1 libgjs0g
  libglib-object-introspection-perl libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-dev
  libglib2.0-dev-bin libgweather-3-16 libllvm12 libp11-kit0 libpostproc55
  libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libpython3.9 libpython3.9-minimal
  libpython3.9-stdlib libqt5webengine-data libqt5webengine5
  libqt5webenginecore5 libswresample3 libswscale5 libwayland-client0
  libwayland-server0 p11-kit p11-kit-modules python2.7 python2.7-minimal
  python3-cffi-backend python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3.9 python3.9-minimal
  qml-module-qtwebengine yaru-theme-gnome-shell
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 64 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: You seem to have repositories for three versions of Ubuntu in your sources list: 16.04 (Bionic), 21.04 (Hirsute), and 21.10 (Impish). Have you needed to install specific versions of libraries to install certain software? 

Comment: @matigo - I started out with installing 20.04 but was facing some issues as it was a clean install on new SSD. So I installed 18.04, upgraded to 20.04. To try to learn about the new features (forgive me if this was stupid to do) I then upgraded to 21.10 yesterday. As of now many of the programs I installed while using 20.04 aren't running (like stremio) so I am considering going back to it, but I'd like it if I didn't have to.

Comment: @mikewhatever tried, didn't work.

Comment: How did you go from 20.04 to 21.10? There is no direct upgrade path ... 

Comment: @matigo - sorry about that. 20.04 to 21.04 to 21.10.

Comment: That is still not something one can do in a weekend. One cannot go from 20.04 to 21.04 without "skipping steps", which would result in various complications. Given that you've said that you're still learning, perhaps a fresh install of 21.10 would be the fastest way to resolve your issue.

Comment: @matigo - I had been using 20.04 for about a month before deciding to go for non-LTS version. I went to 
- "software & updates > updates"
- subscribed to "all updates"
- "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" to "For any new version".

I received pop-up after a while mentioning 21.04 being available and post upgrading to that I got another for 21.10.

I will still try to look for more possible solutions but if none work then I'll do a clean install of 21.10. 

Thanks :)

Comment: The release-upgrader, if it runs without error, cleans up old apt sources automatically. Your apt sources, however, are a bit of a mess...which suggests that there were errors you missed or ignored. Those unseen errors would explain why your release-upgrade to 21.10 seems incomplete. @matigo is right; a clean install is the safest and easiest way to remove whatever unknown problem is preventing completion of the release-upgrade.

Comment: Alternately, to find out the actual undisclosed problem so you can fix it, simply review your logs: /var/log/apt/term.log.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)